# How to determine folder vs branch with tf command?

Tags: tfs, tfvc, tfs-2012

I have this example where FolderA had sub FolderB and they were both folders, until I branched FolderB to FolderB-branch. Then both sub folder turned into branches.

[image]

How can I use `tf command` to determine what is folder and what is branch?

`tf dir /r` and `tf dir /r /folders` show the same info.

How can I use tf command to distinguish what is what?

TFS 11, Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: I don't think you can. The distinction between a folder and a branch in TFVC is primarily in metadata and doesn't affect very much. What is your use-case for needing this information?

Comment: @DanielMann trying to replicate the look so it looks like original view in Team explorer, `dir` command doesn't say what it is.

Comment: Still not clear on what the objective is. Why are you trying to "replicate" team explorer?

Comment: Not replicating team explorer. Just the hierarchy view of folders. Like a summary of the TFS server instance, that can be then exported as html file. The icons should be same.

Comment: @DanielMann you commented: `"...is primarily in metadata..."`, is this info available with `tf command`?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to be. It's probably available via the SOAP APIs but I haven't looked at the TFS 2012 object model in at least half a decade. TFVC is pretty much dead and you're unlikely to find a lot of people who remember much about TFS 2012 given that it's almost 10 years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way do this, using `tf branches` command. When using it, TFS returns 2 responses:

when item is a **Folder**:

```
Item FolderA is not used in any branch view
```

when item is a **Branch**, it lists branch tree, like:

```
../FolderB
>>  ../FolderB-branch
```

Now we can parse the output and assign if item is a `Folder` or a `Branch`.

Of course, the command `tf branches` need to be run in parent folder or with full parameters like /collection and others, if required.